# How to Validate JSON Input using Requests? Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am sending some data with formData, and for one fields (object) I use: `JSON.stringify(this.allValues)`.
and I try to validate all values from `this.allValues` .
Till now I tried 2 methods from [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-validate-json-input-using-requests?page=1) , now I try with the second one with "JsonApiMiddleware" .
But with this I  validation(required) errors, even if the fields are not null.

```
public function rules()
    {
        $newValues = json_decode(request()->get('all_values')); // Here I have all values that needs to be validated
        dd($newValues); // I post the respons for this below
        $newValues = [
               'saleforce_id'                    => 'required',
               'customer_id'                     => 'required',
        ]

        return $newValues;
}
```

> ""customer_id":49,"saleforce_id":"","lkp_invoicing_method_id":3,"lkp_product_category_id":10,"lkp_notice_period_id":5,"lkp_licence_term_id":9,"is_attrition_risk":false,"is_additional_users":false,"contract_value_exc_vat_annual":"257590...and many more

Comment: Why don't you create a rule `php artisan make:rule MyJsonRule` then try to validate the data within the rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.
I use the method from [laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-validate-json-input-using-requests?page=1), fureszpeter, method with middleware, and I edit it.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->has('all_values')) {
            $request->merge([
                'all_values' => json_decode($request->get('all_values'), true)
            ]);
        }  // only when I have all_values in my request

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**In my existing Request:**

```
public function rules()
{
    $newValues = [
               'all_values.saleforce_id'         => 'required'
               'all_values.customer_id'          => 'required',
               // and the rest of the files
    ]

    return $newValues
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Treat the JSON object you send as a php associative array. For example let's say your sent data looks like this.

```
/* var allValues = */
{
    data: {
        requiredField1: value,
        requiredField2: value,
        requiredArrayField1: [
            1,
            2,
            3,
        ],
        optionalField1: value
    }
}
```

Then, you can validate the data like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    return: [
        'data' => 'required|array',
        'data.requiredField1' => 'required',
        'data.requiredField2' => 'required',
        'data.requiredArrayField1' => 'required|array',
        'data.requiredArrayField1.*' => 'required|numeric',
        'data.optionalField1' => 'nullable',
    ];
}
```

Comment: I tried to use ex: 'all_values.customer_id' , but the value is still null.

Comment: Don't use `JSON.stringify(this.allValues)`, it will send a string instead of a json object.

Comment: Ok, but the value is, formData.append('all_values', this.allValues);. because I have 3 appends in this call, one of them is a file, and if I don't use JSON... on server I get [object ,object], and I am not sure how to validate this.

Comment: Remove the form request for now. Go to your controller method and place a `dd($request->all());`. This will help you see how the data you sent is structured and how to validate it.

Comment: It's  an array of objects, and without formData, my old validation worked . But now I need a single post request, with all that values,  and the files.